# (VBA-EXCEL) Automatically change and increment the value of an activex textbox based from a cell value

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have an **activex textbox** in `worksheet1` that needs to **automatically change** based on the **cell value** which is in `worksheet2` (where my table is).
This value should be **incremented**, like the concept of ID Number which increments if you add a customer,the incremented value **must be displayed at the textbox** ready to be saved.

Does anyone have any constructive suggestion concerning the above?

Comment: If you could add pieces of your code with what you tried we could help you improve and fix it. Else we can't do much.

Comment: So in a way are you trying to show the total count of records in Sheet2? Eg. Sheet2 has 5 rows filled so the textbox should show 6?

Comment: my record is not definite, i mean there are blank cells in my table. I need to base my value (for the textbox) from the last data in that particular column, then increment it and display it to the textbox.

Comment: Hello Krynce! I've tentatively edited your question - no need for it to be chatty like a forum post. Unfortunately I'm still unsure exactly what you want to achieve - can you add some screenprints from worksheet1 and worksheet2?

Comment: I can't add images, need more reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly paste the below code in worksheets(2) of your workbook. Also txtVal is the name of textbox on Worksheets(1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Assuming A1 is the cell in worksheet 2 and it has numeric value as it should be incremented.

    If Target.Count = 1 And Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then Sheet1.txtVal.Text = CInt(Target.Value) + 1
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've tried this, but I got an error which says Overflow and highlights the Sheet1.txtVal.Text so on and so forth. :( I did changed the sheet1 as the name of my sheet and the txtbox name too, and the address. nothing. :(

Comment: Change Cint to Clng and run the code again. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Still no display at the textbox.

Comment: @krynce I have updated the answers with screenshot. Kindly follow the same process and let me know if its working for you. Also let me know which version of excel you are using.

Comment: Still not working. I even tried to test this to a new workbook. I am using version 2013.

Comment: Try to replace `SelectionChange` into `Change`. Than put any value in A1 in Sheet2. You should see the result while I see it. Than improve if you need.

Comment: @Kaz Jaw  thanks   my mistake. It should be change event. I have updated the answer.